# preventing audio from playing then allowing after end with jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I have been working on a simple audio player for a site.  I only want it to have play and stop capabilities.  I have it working so that it will play, set it so playing cant overlap by unbinding the selector.  After it is finished I want to bind the selector again.  It doesn't seem to do it.  Maybe I am just not understanding where bind and unbind should be placed.

```
function playMusic(){
    var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
    var audioElementSrc = $(this).attr('data-audio-src');
    audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioElementSrc);
    $.get();
    audioElement.addEventListener("loadeddata", function(){
        audioElement.play();                
    }, true);

    $('.pause').click(function() {
        audioElement.pause();
    });
    audioElement.addEventListener("playing", function(){
        $('.play').unbind('click');
    });
    audioElement.addEventListener("ended", function(){
        $('.play').bind('click');           
    });
}

$(function(e){
    $('.play').click(playMusic);
});
```

Comment: This seems like a really inefficient way to do this. Have you considered just storing a boolean in a data element to say whether or not it's playing? That way you don't need to bind and unbind every play button on the page each time one is clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you rebind the event, you are not passing any listener to the bind. You have to explicitly point to the function which to call on click again. There is also no rebind for the pause event.

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/kfkszwr1/1/

I have added these event listeners:

```
audioElement.addEventListener("pause", rebind);
audioElement.addEventListener("ended", rebind);
```

Comment: That is it!  Thanks I didn't realize that I needed a separate function to rebind.  That works perfectly!

Comment: There are simpler ways to do this though, please consider @sage88 comment. You will also have to consider binding and unbinding the pause button and this starts to become a lot of hassle.

Comment: I have tried storing variables then using if else statements, and so far haven't been able to get them to work.  I will keep working to see if I can come up with a way to do it without bind and unbind.

Answer (score 0):

This does not answer your immediate question, but will help you with using data elements if you would like to use a more efficient approach.

Set a boolean variable using jQuery data element:

```
$('#data_div').data("isPlaying", true);
```

Retrieve boolean variable using jQuery data element:

```
var isPlaying = $('#data_div').data("isPlaying");
```

Just make sure you actually have a div on the page with the id "data_div".

Comment: I think I have it all working corretly.  Not exactly the way you suggested, but without using bind and unbind.  See right below for code.   Thanks for pointing me in a different direction.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var isPlaying = false;
    function playMusic(){
        var audioElement = document.createElement('audio');
        var audioElementSrc = $(this).attr('data-audio-src');               

        if (isPlaying != true)
        {
            isPlaying = true;
            audioElement.setAttribute('src', audioElementSrc);
            $.get();
            audioElement.addEventListener("loadeddata", function(){
            audioElement.play();                
            }, true);
             audioElement.addEventListener("ended", function() {
             isPlaying = false;    
            });         
            $('.pause').click(function() {
            audioElement.pause();
            isPlaying = false
            });             
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }           
    }

$(function(e){
    $('.play').click(playMusic);
```